# Boolean not working like it should?

Tags: python

```
imgfound=False
imgexists=0
img_ext=['.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif']

while True:

    httpfind=html.find('http',imgexists)
    if httpfind==-1:
        break
    imgexists=httpfind

    imgexist=html.find('"',imgexists)
    imgurl=html[imgexists:imgexist]
    imgexists+=len(imgurl)

    for extscan in img_ext:
        if not imgurl.find(extscan)==-1:
            imgfound=True
            break

    #print imgfound 

    if imgfound==False:
        continue

    print imgurl
```

I want to find links to images in a html document. But something is not working like it should. Like it prints all links regardless of whether they have a img_ext substring in them. I printed the value in imgfound, and for all the links it is True. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
not imgurl.find(extscan) == -1
```

will evaluate to `False` for every integer, because of operators precedence.

**How can you fix it?**

- Change it to

  ```
  imgurl.find(extscan) != -1
  ```
- Or, change it to

  ```
  not(imgurl.find(extscan) == -1)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Christian's answer is correct, but it's worth noting that this is not good Python style. The preferred form is:

```
if extscan not in imgurl
```

Your version looks like a Java-ism.